# How can I alter the type of a money-column to decimal in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, alter-table, money

I have a table in PostgreSQL where one column "vat" has type `money` but I would like to alter it to `decimal` instead.

How can I do it?

I tried with:

```
alter table my_table alter column vat type decimal;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "vat" cannot be cast to type numeric
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try providing `USING` clause as described in [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html):

> A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

Comment: Por ejemplo:  alter table my_table alter column vat type decimal using vat::decimal;